# Экспоненциальная запись в TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как в `DataGridTextColumn` реализовать переход на экспоненциальную запись, когда не хватает места для полного отображения числа.

Желаемый эффект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть идея использовать конвертор, и вызывать его всякий раз при изменении ширины колонки. В конверторе использовать `StringFormat`. Возникают дополнительные вопросы:

- на какое событие нужно подписаться которое бы отслеживало изменение размера колонки?
- как определять сколько символов влезает в ячейку, чтобы знать сколько символов отобразить после запятой и до `E`?

P.S. Что-то подобное делает свойство `TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"` у TextBlock. при нехватке места для отображения часть символов заменяется многоточием. Если узнать каким способом TextBlock определяет что ему не хватает места отобразить текст, то может и получиться решить данный вопрос.

Comment: По идее тут упирается в кастомный контрол и DataGridTemplateColumn . Это может быть наследник TextBlock или attached property, который при изменении размера как-то определит, что содержимое не влезает и поменяет запись. Значит остается выяснить это "как-то"

Comment: Весь вопрос на какое событие нужно подписаться, чтобы можно было отслеживать ширину колонки. Вы нашли это событие?

Comment: @Bulson, в процессе, отпишусь если найду.

Comment: Я уже нашел... , но пока не дописал как вычислять необходимую ширину на нужное кол-во символов. Если хотите могу выложить в ответ, но ответом это все же не будет, т.к. нет конечного результата.

Comment: @Bulson, выкладывайте, а ответ потом можно дополнить.

Comment: Вот выложил начало. Если `Width="Auto"`, то на старте программы можно засечь необходимый минимальный размер, а дальше плясать от него, так думаю.

Comment: Я удалю черновик потому, что это тупиковый путь. Видимо, надо думать в направлении `DataTemplateSelector`: создать набор `DataTemplate` c различным StringFormat. И написать класс унаследованный от  `DataTemplateSelector` ,в котором пытаться в зависимости от ширины выбирать тот или иной `DataTemplate`.

Comment: От размера шрифта зависит сколько символов уместится в ячейку заданного размера. От количества доступных символов можно сделать зависимость формата отображения. В GDI+ есть `Graphics.MeasureString` для получения размера отображаемой строки, если получили больше чем надо - меняем формат отображения и повторяем пока не получим желаемый размер. Наверняка есть аналог и в WPF

Comment: @rdorn, с размером строки теперь понятно, спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По идее, для этого можно приспособить `UserControl` и немного code-behind. Для измерения ширины текста без отображения подойдёт класс `FormattedText`. Вот простой набросок:

Контрол:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.DoubleWidthFitControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBlock Name="Target" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</UserControl>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class DoubleWidthFitControl : UserControl
{
    public DoubleWidthFitControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SizeChanged += (o, args) => Recalc();
    }

    #region dp double Value
    public double Value
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Value", typeof(double), typeof(DoubleWidthFitControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(0.0, (o, args) => ((DoubleWidthFitControl)o).Recalc()));
    #endregion

    void Recalc()
    {
        var targetWidth = ActualWidth;
        var num = Value;

        string s;
        // у C# 7 есть локальные функции, вау!
        bool CheckLength(string format)
        {
            s = num.ToString(format);
            return Measure(s) <= targetWidth;
        }

        if (CheckLength("F") || CheckLength("G"))
        {
            Target.Text = s;
            return;
        }

        int i;
        for (i = 0; CheckLength($"E{i}"); i++)
            /**/;
        if (i == 0)
            Target.Text = "###";
        else
            Target.Text = num.ToString($"E{i - 1}");
    }

    double Measure(string s)
    {
        TextBlock tb = Target;
        var formattedText = new FormattedText(
            s,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            tb.FlowDirection,
            new Typeface(tb.FontFamily, tb.FontStyle, tb.FontWeight, tb.FontStretch),
            tb.FontSize,
            Brushes.Black);
        return formattedText.Width;
    }
}
```

Использовать просто:

```
<local:DoubleWidthFitControl Value="10000000000" />
```

Результат:

[image: анимашка]

Есть хороший потенциал для дальнейшей оптимизации. Например, при данной строке и шрифте можно один раз подсчитать и запомнить варианты отображения с их размерами, и просто подбирать наибольший вписывающийся.

Comment: Здорово! Интересно как будет вести себя приложение, если в каждую ячейку DataGrid засунуть такой кастомный контрол.

Comment: @S.Kost: Я надеюсь, будет не сильно тормозить :) Если будет, нужно смотреть в сторону оптимизаций, да. // Рад, что оказалось полезным.

Comment: а почему Measure не локальная функция? :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Хм, и правда :)