# Полное содержимое Ячейки DataGrid при наведении

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Приветствую!

Есть достаточно большая таблица, содержимое столбцов которой очень неоднородно. Например 10 строк в столбце имеют длину ~ 10-12 символов а последняя 20-30. Из за этого не удобно использовать фиксированную ширину столбцов - 11 строка не влазит. Но устанавливать ширину по контенту тоже не всегда уместно - т.к. из за одной длинной строки будет расшириться весь столбец. На мониторах с небольшим разрешением все еще хуже. Собственно вопрос - как реализовать такое, что бы в столбцах отображались,  например первые 12 символов а при наведении уже полное содержимое ячейки ?

Сам датагрид :

```
<DataGrid Style="{StaticResource StyleTable}" x:Name="DGInvestmentDetails"
          Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"
          ItemsSource="{Binding InvestCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          RowHeight="24" IsReadOnly="True" 
          CurrentCell="{Binding CellInfo, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Margin="0,0,0,71">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Type}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Currency" MinWidth="50" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Units" MinWidth="90" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Units}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Aq.Price" MinWidth="80" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding AqPr}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quote" MinWidth="80" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Quote}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Isin" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Isin}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Market Value" MinWidth="100" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Markedvalue}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Market Value USD" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding MarkedvalueUSD}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Profit USD" MinWidth="100" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding profit}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Percent" MinWidth="80" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Percent}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Valuation Date" MinWidth="100" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding currentDate}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: ммм, а `ToolTip` пробовали устанавливать?

Comment: Где-то, кстати, здесь на ruSO видел реализацию конвертера (вроде от @VladD, если он придет в топик - может найдет), которая отсекала строку и добавляла в нее `...`, если она не вмещается в отведенное пространство. Вот это отсеченное значение установить как Text для TextBlock, а полное значение - как ToolTip

Comment: @Андрей  `ToolTip` не ставил и не пользовался. Разве он заменит `DataGrid` ?

Comment: Зачем заменит? Переопределяете CellTemplate (или как он там в гриде называется) и ставите вместо него TextBlock, которому устанавливаете ToolTip

Comment: @Андрей Я не понимаю, что вы имеете в виду )

Comment: `DataGridTemplateColumn` с текстблоком, так яснее?

Comment: @Андрей: Вот это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/637995/10105?

Comment: @VladD, хм, да, похоже. Но мне казалось, что я видел именно со строкой и с `...`. Может спутал, а может в другом месте видел...

Comment: @Андрей: Ну должна прокатить та же идея с немного другим code-behind.

Comment: @VladD, ну это - да

Comment: @VladD ok, спасибо опробую!

Comment: @Сергей, вы для начала просто ToolTip попробуйте, может вам сразу это подойдет. Или вы не поняли как это сделать? Могу оформить ответом

Comment: @Андрей Буду признателен, если оформите как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример разметки с использованием `ToolTip`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Имя" Width="100">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Возраст" Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Адрес" Width="100">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" ToolTip="{Binding Address}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Именно то, что доктор прописал!

Comment: Не подскажите, как называется инструмент - когда при нажатии на строку в DataGrid таблица разворачивается на новую строку с контентом? Не могу название вспомнить.

Comment: @Сергей: [детали строк (row details)](https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/UI_WPF/level22/22_10.php) ?

Comment: Да, точно! Плюсанул бы вам 2 раза если бы мог. Еще раз спасибо.